# Expose object JSON straight from database - Writing a Format[anorm.Pk[Long]]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

Hello  all :) I'm about 16 hours new to Scala and Play!Framework (version 2.1). I'm following [this Play!2.0 tutorial with Anorm](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku), which uses Jerkson. From [what I understand](http://eng.42go.com/working-with-json-in-play-2-1/), in 2.1 you can do that out of the box, as long as you have the right JSON Formatters.

So here is the JSON service:

```
def listBars() = Action {
  val bars = Bar.findAll()
  Ok(Json.toJson(bars)).as("application/json")
}
```

And here is Bar.scala:

```
case class Bar(id: Pk[Long], name: String)
object Bar {
  implicit var anormLongPkFormat = new Format[Pk[Long]] {
    def writes(key: Pk[Long]): JsValue = Json.toJson(key.toString)
    def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[Pk[Long]] = JsSuccess( -?- )
  }
  implicit val barFormat = Json.format[Bar]

  def findAll(): Seq[Bar] = {...}
}
```

I'm using `Json.format[Bar]`, but it tells me he needs another formatter for `anorm.Pk[Long]`. I don't need the `reads` method, for the moment, I only want to serve the values; But the compiler needs a `reads` method. I'm totally at a loss at how to make it compile, let alone at how to write a good `reads`.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need `reads` now, then the easiest way is not to implement it's logic and return an error:

`def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[Pk[Long]] = JsError()`